# Security problems on Ubuntu OpenERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-6

Hi I have this code with the xml file and cvs and works perfectly on my openerp 7 on windows but I have a virtualbox machine with ubuntu 12 server. I tried to install the same module and brings me an error why? can anyone help me?

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">

        <record id="group_monitoreo" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Monitoreo</field>
        </record>

        <record id="group_tecnicos" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Tecnicos</field>
        </record>

        <record id="group_sucursales" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Sucursales</field>
        </record>

        <record id="group_supmonitoreo" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Supervisor Monitoreo</field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

xml.view

```
<menuitem id="submenu_monitoreo_ordenes" 
parent="monitoreo_ordenes_menu" 
name= 'Monitoreo' sequence="10"   
groups="group_monitoreo,group_tecnicos,group_sucursales"/>
```

error
No such external ID currently defined in the system: ordenes.group_monitoreo
this error pops when i install this module on ubuntu but in wondows never comes. why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the error message to your question, otherwise it's hard for anyone to help you without knowing what went wrong.

Comment: No such external ID currently defined in the system: ordenes.group_monitoreo

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't just post in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you created that group_monitoreo in `.csv` file or in OpenERP `Settings -> Users -> Groups`?

If you have created a group in setting please create a security group in .csv file so that it'll work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share the solution, i removed all groups in all xml files i installed, the module then i wrote all groups as same as the were and voala!! works, i dont know why but i will make more things to discover why i can install the module on windows without problems and in ubuntu the security get me errors thanks for your help